# ListView não apresenta primeiro item no android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, listview

Olá, Tudo bem? eu to com um problema ao usar o listView do android, percebo que ele mostra somente a partir do segundo item, e em caso de somente um item na lista ele não mostra nada.

Vou mostrar meus códigos

OnCreate do MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gridView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gridview_listaCategoria);

    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    DataBaseManager.initializeInsyance(myDbHelper);

    try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();

    }catch(SQLException sqle){

        throw sqle;

    }
    CategoriaSQL categoriaSQL = new CategoriaSQL();
    arrayAdapter = categoriaSQL.getAlllitas(this);
    gridView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

para exibir isso tenho 2 layouts:
1) activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="br.com.dorgamnetwork.calculadora.MainActivity">
    <include layout="@layout/lista_categoria" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

e o lista_categoria.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/gridview_listaCategoria"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

CategoriaSQL

```
public class CategoriaSQL {
    private String [] AllColumns ={DataBase.TABLE_CATEGORIA_ID, DataBase.TABLE_CATEGORIA_NOME,DataBase.TABLE_CATEGORIA_DESCRICAO,DataBase.TABLE_CATEGORIA_IMAGEM};

public ArrayAdapter<Categoria> getAlllitas(Context context){
    SQLiteDatabase database = DataBaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
    ArrayAdapter<Categoria> categorias = new ArrayAdapter<Categoria>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBase.TABLE_CATEGORIA,AllColumns,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        Categoria categoria = cursorToLista(cursor);
        categorias.add(categoria);

    }
    cursor.close();
    DataBaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase();
    return categorias;
}

private Categoria cursorToLista(Cursor cursor) {
    Categoria lista = new Categoria();
    lista.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    lista.setNome(cursor.getString(1));
    lista.setDescricao(cursor.getString(2));
    lista.setImagem(cursor.getString(3));
    return lista;
}
```

}

Comment: Já tive um problema semelhante, tenta verificar se o item não fica embaixo ta toolbar, você pode fazer um teste tirando o toolbar da aplicação.

Comment: @Danilo D se puder, inclua o código da classe CategoriaSQL?

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni eu fiz a remoção mas ela continua sem mostrar o item 1

Comment: @RodrigoPaixão fiz a adição da classe

Comment: O problema esta na leitura do cursor.  Você aponta para a primeira posição e quando entra no **while** você ta chamando o comando next que pega o segundo elemento do cursor.

Comment: Tente usar o **do while**.  Isso deve resolver.

Comment: Sim, eu vi esse erro, muito grato pela dica, usei um do while.